# Algorithm so that i can index 2^n combinations in a way so i can backtrack from any index value of 1 to 2^n without using an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to do something but it is outside my field. To explain lets set n=3 to simplify things where n is the total number of the parameters in this example: A, B, C. These parameters can have a state of ON and OFF (aka 0 or 1).
The total number of combinations of these parameters is 2^n = 8 in this case which can be visualized as:

```
   ABC
1: 000
2: 111
3: 100
4: 010
5: 001
6: 110
7: 011
8: 101
```

Of course the above list can be sorted in (2^n)! = 40320 ways.
I want an algorithm so that i can calculate the state of any of my parameters (0 or 1) given a number from 1 to 2^n. For example if i have the number of 3 using the table above i know state of A is 1 and B and C is 0. Of course you can have a table/array to look it up given a specific sorting, but even for relatively small values of n you need to have a huge table.

I'm not familiar with this and the methods you can do indexing that's why i need help.

Kind regards

Comment: If you don't need the exact order listed above, then it's just counting in binary.

Comment: While I don't know the specific answer, you should probably search for something related to "enumerating permutations". There are quite a few way to generate and/or recall specific permutation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations) But there's more steps to make it do what you want...

Comment: I do not need an exact list, i want a way so i can calculate the state of any parameter for any value of 1 to 2^n which requires a consistent method of indexing. I will look into this but i'm not a computer programmer nor an electrical/electronic engineer, so any info is appreciated.

Comment: @melpomene I believe the poster wants a function `f(P, i)` where `P` is the permutation number and `i` is the index in that specific permutation. Binary counting is just one specific case of it (`f(0, i)` for example)

Comment: I think @melpomene has a nice solution now that i looked into it. viraptor yes a specific case like binary counting looks to work great in this case since i do not need a specific way of indexing, it just needs to be consistent and allow me to have all combinations. I only need to right a function to do basically conversion between binary and decimal in both ways and the rest are easy :)

Comment: Ah, that's kind of disappointing, your original question is a really interesting one :D

Comment: @viraptor yes i knew that there would have been an easy solution but it is almost 5am and i'm sick, so even if i had experience in this i would probably get stuck like last time i posted such a question here xD Thanks again though for the reply :)

Comment: @melpomene You should post your comment as an answer so i can select it:)

Answer (score 0):

Just realised you can actually look at it another way. What you want is a function encrypting N bits to another set of N bits. In practice this is the same as [format preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). The question is, do you care whether:

- all `2^n` cases are covered, or just a large enough number close to `2^n` (you have to choose the right encryption/hash method)
- you want to do this one way or both ways (that is, do you ever want to ask - I have this number corresponding to that number, which permutation am I using)

If the answer is no to both, you can just find an FPE algorithm that doesn't require you to generate the whole table (some do).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i think you misunderstood the problem. It would be really difficult to explain what i am trying to achieve here, but binary counting is a very good solution to my case since for any n the array of combinations that will be generated will always be the same, and it is easy to get the state of each parameter by assigning each parameter to a specific digit of the binary number. In the example above if you set 1st digit to A, 2nd to B etc then for any 2^n-1 decimal i get an individual n digit binary of different value that is consistent for any n :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen another problem of [finding all subsets of a given set using bitmask](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/71059/finding-all-subset-of-given-set-using-bitmask). You can use the same concept in your case. This [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/) contains a good tutorial.

Comment: yes that's basically what i'm trying to do just is the indexing that's my problem, not generating the set. Nice links although, binary counting as melpomene mentioned is the solution to my problem:)